# Long build times for Jekyll menu

Tags: optimization, build, menu, jekyll

I currently have a navigation menu in Jekyll, it works well except that... it doesn't scale so well.
I have around 250 posts, it takes 45 seconds to create my website, 35 of which only for the navigation menu !

The navigation menu itself is basic, list all posts, group them by month, months being grouped by years.
But this is used for all posts each time I create a new one, if i use incremental build each post will only have a navigation menu to older posts, not to newer post i create after it.

So here is my question(s):

- Can i capture the menu when building the site, and thus only create the menu once and use my captured variable in my template ?

OR

- Can i create a html file that i would include in my template, and just updating that file would update my older posts' navigation menu ?

My current code for creating the menu is :

```
{% assign curYear= site.time | date: '%Y' %}
{% assign curMonth= site.time | date: '%-m' | minus: 1 %}
{% assign months = "Janvier|Février|Mars|Avril|Mai|Juin|Juillet|Août|Septembre|Octobre|Novembre|Décembre" | split: "|" %}
<div class="l1">{{ curYear }}</div>
<div class="l2">{{ months[curMonth] }}</div>
{% for cpage in site.posts %}
{% assign postYear = cpage.date | date: "%Y" %}
{% assign postMonth = cpage.date | date: "%-m" | minus: 1 %}
{% if postYear != curYear %}
{% assign curYear= postYear %}
<div class="l1">{{ curYear }}</div>
{% endif %}
{% if postMonth != curMonth %}
{% assign curMonth= postMonth %}
<div class="l2">{{ months[curMonth] }}</div>
{% endif %}
{% if cpage.url == page.url %}
{% assign active= "class='active'" %}
{% else %}
{% assign active= "" %}
{% endif %}
<div class="l3">
<a href="{{ cpage.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}" {{active}} >{{ cpage.title }}</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The final rendering is a list of years containing months, which contains blog posts.
When I use the --profile option of jekyll i have:

```
    Filename                                            | Count |     Bytes |   Time
    ----------------------------------------------------+-------+-----------+-------
    _layouts/blog.html                                  |   183 | 39809.20K | 38.175
    _includes/menu-left-blog.html                       |   183 | 37879.87K | 37.902
```

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: Any hint on where i can find a better way to format my question or to give it a better content so i can edit/remove this one ?

Comment: JRS, I assume you have traced your performance issues using Jekyll. Can you maybe update your post so we can see how this trace actually looks. Also, can you please let us know how you exactly are generating the menu. I have that number of posts in my blog as well, and it's takes just 2 seconds or so. Show some code, please :)

Comment: Thank you Christian for this very constructive idea ! I edited the original post to include a bit of code and the first two lines of the build :)

Comment: Except for your build times, I don't see anything extraordinary :-( The "count" is not extraordinary high, I have my navigation used 759 times. Of course, your nav is pretty big, so... can you try to comment everything inside the loop? I would love to know if this code is actually increasing the build time so much or if it is something else maybe.

Comment: Deleting everything inside the loop reduces the build time to 7 seconds.
Is there a way (appart from deleting every line one by one) to know what instruction takes time ?
One idea that was proposed was to generate the navigation ONCE, and include it in every blog post without calculating it, is there a way to do such a thing ?

Comment: @JRS 7 seconds is still too much. I don't know a way to debug it in that a way you want it (I am not a Ruby expert, maybe google debug ruby or something). You could - in theory - perpare that file statically as an include. You could use a "Generator" plugin. But honestly, I think you are using some statement which messes it up. Maybe it is to be found in some other file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Generator plugin, i'll make myself one to include the navigation menu !